# Using quantifier get truth value

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In each case below say whether the given statement is  true for whcih universe

$(0,1)={{(x\in R: 0<x<1})}$

$[0,1]={{(x\in R: 0\le x \le1})}$

$\exists y(\forall x( x>y)$

This means there exists an real number that all other number are greater than it. This is probably true I think in the closed [0,1] universe because zero can be this number. But then zero cant be greater than zero.

$\exists y (\forall x(x\ge y)$

This mean there exist a number that every number is greater or equal to it. I think it true in close [0,1] universe because zero is this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is false in both universes, because zero does not belong to the universe $(0, 1)$, and for any other choice of a real number $y\in (0, 1)$, there will always be some $x\in (0, 1)$ such that $x\lt y$. If we look at the universe of all reals in $[0, 1]$, $y = 0$ would be a candidate for the existence of a real number less than all others in the universe, except when $x=0$: $x=0$  cannot be strictly greater than $y = 0$.  Hence the first proposition is false in either universe.

The second is indeed true in $[0, 1]$: Put $y = 0 \in [0, 1]$. Then every $x\in [0, 1]$, including $x = 0$, is greater than or  equal to $y=0$. (The second statement is not true in $(0, 1)$, for the same reason the first isn't true in $(0, 1))$.